# Is there an event to fires when activity run?

Tags: java, android

[image]

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_test); do{ //actions //In this point the elements not shows }while(condicion); } } 
@Override protected void onStart() { super.onStart(); //In this point the elements not shows }
```

**Is there an event to fires after elements appear?**
(without invoke onPause() event)

Comment: What do you mean? "buttons and textview" appear when you call `setContentView`.

Comment: When the activity starts, it become automatically visible to the user, without the need to invoke any method except for the `onCreate()` in which you define the layout to use and other behavior.

Comment: Your question looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please rephrase your question with "what you want to do before/after something happened in an activity's life cycle".

Comment: @user2342558 They appear after the `setContentView` in `onCreate` is called (if you call it at all). Don't even have to wait for `onCreate` to end.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an event to fires when activity starts?

Yes, it is called `onStart()` as you see in the diagram you posted in your question.

> Is there an event to fires after elements appear? (without invoke onPause() event)

No, the elements in your event are available immediately after you call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` so there is no need for an event.

This sounds like you are trying to solve a problem that you think requires such an event. Please post a new question explaining what you want to do, including how the user interacts with your app and what you want to appear on the screen. We can point you to the correct way to accomplish this using the Android API.

Comment: Sorry was run, I want to know if there is a event in "Activity is running"

Comment: @Oliver No, "Activity is running" in the diagram is not a single event. This is where your app processes app events such as button clicks, key events, etc.